# Cannot add searchbar in dropdownlist

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap-3

I created my first project in ASP.Net framework with MVC and I am trying to include a dropdownlist with searching capabilities.  I am trying to create something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xr6Hx.png), but I keep ending up with [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uF5dh.png).  I have tried bootstrap selectpicker, select2, and others but I can't seem to change the style of the dropdown.

Here is my code:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.selectpicker').selectpicker({
            liveSearch: true,
            showSubtext: true
        });
    });
</script>
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.MaterialPN, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @*@Html.EditorFor(model => model.MaterialPNID, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })*@
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.MaterialPNID, ViewBag.MaterialPNListItems as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>, new
        {
            @class = "form-control selectpicker",
            data_show_subtext = "true",
            data_live_search = "true"
        })
    </div>
</div>
```

EDIT:
I created a totally new, vanilla solution to test this out.  In visual studio I created a new ASP.Net C# solution with MVC, then added the Bootstrap-select library in NuGet.

```
public class Student
    {
        public int StudentId { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Name")]
        public string StudentName { get; set; }
        public Gender StudentGender { get; set; }
    }

    public enum Gender
    {
        Male,
        Female,
        Other
    }
```

And added a dropdown to the about page:

```
@using SearchableDropdown.Models
@model Student
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "About";
}
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.selectpicker').selectpicker({
            liveSearch: true,
            showSubtext: true
        });
    });
</script>
<h2>@ViewBag.Title.</h2>
<h3>@ViewBag.Message</h3>

<p>Use this area to provide additional information.</p>
@Html.DropDownList("StudentGender",
                    new SelectList(Enum.GetValues(typeof(Gender))),
                    "Select Gender",
                    new
                    {
                        @class = "form-control selectpicker",
                        data_show_subtext = "true",
                        data_live_search = "true"
                    })
```

I am still seeing the same thing, a dropdown without clear searching capability.  When I have the dropdown selected and start typing, it will choose the item that starts with the letters that I type but this is not true searching capability.

Comment: I solved this issue by watching [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JeawBGzSZYU).

Answer (score 0):

Use below link
https://select2.org/getting-started/basic-usage#multi-select-boxes-pillbox

HTML

```
<select class="js-example-basic-multiple" name="states[]" multiple="multiple">
  <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
    ...
  <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
</select>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.js-example-basic-multiple').select2();
});
```

Comment: This did not work.  It created a new box which is also not searchable.